# How to check if a given variable has the same value as another jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 fields that I would like to check if their values are equal with  `"current_outstanding_balance"` If so, it adds text to the field `"current_outstanding_balance_check"` . It's working when i add one var to loop. But i tried add more like, but it's not working.
 `if(overduer && overdue == fieldNameForResult)`

This is my code:

````
function(){
   var fieldNameForResult = thisPointer.entity.getValue('current_outstanding_balance');
   var overduer = thisPointer.entity.getValue('additional_personnel_costs');
   var overdue = thisPointer.entity.getValue('overdue');


   if(overduer && overdue == fieldNameForResult){
       jQ('[id="current_outstanding_balance_check"]').val('True' );


   }else{
       jQ('[id="current_outstanding_balance_check"]').val('False' );


   }

} ```

Now I have no error, but it shows me "False" even though both fields are empty.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the check for both values:

```
if(parseFloat(overduer) + parseFloat(overdue) == parseFloat(fieldNameForResult)){
```

Comment: Ok, it works so that I have to enter both the same value and the point is, for example, that one `overduer`  is 50 and the `overdue` is 4, not two 54 . For example ` if(overduer + overdue == fieldNameForResult ){ `

Comment: @Gajka42 so you want to check if 50 + 4 = 54? aka overduer  + overdue = fieldNameForResult

Comment: Yes, if two values achieve the same result as the variable `fieldNameForResult`

Comment: @Gajka42 edited the answer. But this only works if all 3 variables are numeric. if not: `parseFloat(overduer)` for every variable

Comment: No, its no working your edited. I I can see "False" at startup even though there are both 0 values

Comment: i would advise you to console.log the 3 variables. But i really don't understand what the problem is. in this case if overduer = 50 , overdue = 4 and fieldNameForResult = 54 the result is True

Comment: i add parseFloat and its working :)

Comment: Great! To explain the difference: `"50" + "4" = "504"` because they are strings. parseFloat does convert them to floats (50 + 4 = 54)